# After changing user:group the site shows 503 error and even the ipa.ddr.ess:7080 won't let me in; it says "Invalid credentials."

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, user-permissions, litespeed

I accidently used this command in the root directory and now the ipa.ddr.ess:7080 won't let me in; it says "Invalid credentials."
the command that I used was

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /.
```

then I **realized** that it was a mistake then changed most of the directories to root:root using

```
chown -R root:root /to-some-directories manually one by one
the directories in root
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root       4096 May 23 09:32 ./
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root       4096 May 23 09:32 ../
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          7 May 15  2020 bin -> usr/bin/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root       4096 May 22 15:17 boot/
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root      79639 Oct  1  2020 certbot-auto*
-rw-------   1 root root 1028653056 Jun 24  2020 cyberpanel.swap
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root       3780 Jun 15 14:04 dev/
drwxr-xr-x 117 root root      12288 Jun 15 14:38 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root       4096 Jun  4 17:00 home/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          7 May 15  2020 lib -> usr/lib/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          9 May 15  2020 lib32 -> usr/lib32/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          9 May 15  2020 lib64 -> usr/lib64/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root         10 May 15  2020 libx32 -> usr/libx32/
drwx------   2 root root      16384 May 15  2020 lost+found/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root       4096 May 15  2020 media/
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root       4096 Jul 24  2020 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root       4096 Jun 29  2020 opt/
dr-xr-xr-x 144 root root          0 Jun  9 04:50 proc/
drwx------  11 root root       4096 Jun 23 10:00 root/
drwxr-xr-x  32 root root       1000 Jun 23 09:55 run/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root          8 May 15  2020 sbin -> usr/sbin/
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root       4096 Jun 17 07:19 snap/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root       4096 Feb  4 09:40 srv/
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root          0 Jun  9 04:50 sys/
drwxrwxrwt  23 root root    4481024 Jun 23 10:05 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  15 root root       4096 May 22 15:16 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root       4096 May 15  2020 var/
-rw-r--r--   1 root root        384 Jun  9 04:49 webadmin.csr
```

then changed to /home/example.com/public_html to www-data:www-data
the openlitespeed:7080 is not letting me in with CORRECT-Credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the permission of /usr/local/lsws
and changed as follows

```
chown -R nobody:nogroup autoupdate
chown -R nobody:nogroup cachedata
chown -R nobody:nogroup cgid
chown -R nobody:nogroup conf-backup
chown -R lsadm:nogroup conf
chown -R lsadm:nogroup conf-backup
chown -R lsadm:lsadm phpbuild
chown -R nobody:nogroup tmp
```

rebooted the server and then tried to update

```
reboot
sudo apt update
```

it showed following error

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin "sudoers_policy" 
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be owned by uid 0 
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

changed the permissions as follows

```
chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
chown -R root /usr/lib/sudo
```

update and upgrade worked
openlitespeed panel worked as well

Answer (score 1):

Your command was recursive, so it affected every single file and folder in the entire filesystem. You can painstakingly restore the permissions of all of them, but the best option is restoring from your backup.